# Error log with a counter

Tags: c#, counter, logfile

I have a c# project and a log file with errors. I want to give all errors on a new log file out with a counter if there are some errors twice or more. I used the command:

```
bool alreadyExist = fails.Contains(line);
```

This works really good, but I want also a counter, to show how many times I have the same line in a log file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Regex:

```
Regex.Matches(fails, line).Count
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `fails` is an `IEnumerable<string>` where each element is a log file line, this should work:

```
int count = fails.Count((x) => x.Equals(line));
```